# What's the difference between android-security and android-platform tag in aosp source

Tags: android, android-source, custom-rom, lineageos

I was browsing aosp source and found tw o types of tags with latest security patch.

android-security-11.0.0_r71

android-platform-11.0.0_r34

Just curious what's the difference between them!

Can anyone explain in detail what's the difference?